# R package: Quantile regression with multiple group fixed effects and clustered standard error for more than 1 million data points

Tags: r, panel-data, large-data, quantile-regression, clustered-standard-errors

Could you please suggest R package for quantile regression that can include group fixed effects and clustered standard error for more than 1 million data points? I am afraid that `quantreg` can do it. I normally used `felm` package for large dataset, but I have to use quantile regression due to distributional issue with the data.

Any suggestion will be appreciated as I am just stuck to it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=cran+quantile+regression